# Display a Data From JTable into TextArea

Tags: swing, jtable, jtextarea

How can i display a data from a 'specific column' of JTable when a row is selected (table.getvalue(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),'specific column'))into a Textarea.
is there any Listener to make this work ?i mean in every selection the textarea must be updated and take the value of specific column where the row is selected .

Comment: sorry i meant" textarea.setText(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),'specific column')" instead of "table.getvalue(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),'specific column')"

Answer (score 0):

Add a `MouseListener` to the table. When ever user selects the cell then just get the data and set the text to the `TextField`. You can see the demo by running the following code.

[image: Table to TextFiled]

```
private void createUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Object[][] data = {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}};
        Object[] columnNames = {"Col-1", "Col-2"};

        final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

        JPanel btnPnl = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        btnPnl.add(new JLabel("Selected Value: "));
        final JTextField text = new JTextField(10);
        btnPnl.add(text);
        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                if(table.getSelectedRow() != -1 && table.getSelectedColumn() != -1) {
                    String selData = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), table.getSelectedColumn()).toString();
                    text.setText(selData);
                }
            }
        });

        frame.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(btnPnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setTitle("Table to TextField Example.");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: not good enough and you _know_ it ;-) The requirement is:_when a row is selected_ - that can happen by more triggers than mouse ...

Comment: aaah true :-). Let me try other scenarios also and re-post it.

Comment: thank you guys for your answers:-)  but i did my research in internet and i found that i must create a class that implements a ListSelectionListener and invoke the unimplemented method void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e ) and then declare "ListSelectionModel lsm=(ListSelectionModel)e.getSource();

Comment: for (int i = minIndex; i <= maxIndex; i++) {
         if (lsm.isSelectedIndex(i))
.....